# How do I do a Map comprehension with Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary-comprehension

With Python, I can do something like

```
listOfLists = [('a', -1), ('b', 0), ('c', 1)]
my_dict = {foo: bar for foo, bar in listOfLists}

my_dict == {'a': -1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1} => True
```

I know this as a dictionary comprehension. When I look for this operation with Scala, I find [this incomprehensible document](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/111) (pun intended).

Is there an idiomatic way to do this with Scala?

Bonus question: Can I filter with this operation as well like `my_dict = {foo: bar for foo, bar in listOfLists if bar > 0}`?

Comment: What is the type of `listOfLists`?

Comment: It would be helpful to include expected input and output, the snippet of code you've posted is really cryptic to me.

Comment: @sjrd Say it's a List[List[Object]]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let's parse your Python code to figure out what it's doing.

```
my_dict = {
  foo: bar       <-- Key, value names
  for foo, bar   <-- Destructuring a list
  in listOfLists <-- This is where they came from
}
```

So you can see that even in this very short example there's actually considerable redundancy *and* plenty of potential for failure if `listOfLists` isn't actually what it says it is.

If `listOfLists` actually is a list of pairs (key, value), then in Scala it's trivial:

```
listOfPairs.toMap
```

If, on the other hand, it really is lists, and you want to pull off the first one to make the key and save the rest as a value, it would be something like

```
listOfLists.map(x => x.head -> x.tail).toMap
```

You can select some of them by using `collect` instead.  For instance, maybe you only want the lists of length 2 (you could `if x.head > 0` to get your example), in which case you

```
listOfLists.collect{
  case x if x.length == 2 => x.head -> x.last
}.toMap
```

or if it is literally a `List`, you could also

```
listOfLists.collect{
  case key :: value :: Nil => key -> value
}.toMap
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll  compare [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) in Scala2.x and Python 3.x

**1. Sequence**

In python:

```
xs = [x*x for x in range(5)]
#xs = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]

ys = list(map(lambda x: x*x, range(5)))
#ys = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

In Scala:

```
scala> val xs = for(x <- 0 until 5) yield x*x
xs: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 4, 9, 16)

scala> val ys = (0 until 5) map (x => x*x)
ys: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 4, 9, 16)
```

Or you really want a **list**:

```
scala> import collection.breakOut

scala> val xs: List[Int] = (for(x <- 0 until 5) yield x*x)(breakOut)
xs: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 4, 9, 16)

scala> val ys: List[Int] = (0 until 5).map(x => x*x)(breakOut)
ys: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 4, 9, 16)

scala> val zs = (for(x <- 0 until 5) yield x*x).toList
zs: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 4, 9, 16)
```

**2. Set**

In Python

```
s1 = { x//2 for x in range(10) }
#s1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
s2 = set(map(lambda x: x//2, range(10)))
#s2 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

In Scala

```
scala> val s1 = (for(x <- 0 until 10) yield x/2).toSet
s1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val s2: Set[Int] = (for(x <- 0 until 10) yield x/2)(breakOut)
s2: Set[Int] = Set(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val s3: Set[Int] = (0 until 10).map(_/2)(breakOut)
s3: Set[Int] = Set(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val s4 = (0 until 10).map(_/2).toSet
s4: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

**3. Dict**

In Python:

```
pairs = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
#d1 = {1: 'aa', 2: 'bb', 3: 'cc', 4: 'dd'}

d2 = dict([(k*2, v) for k, v in pairs])
#d2 = {2: 'a', 4: 'b', 6: 'c', 8: 'd'}
```

In Scala

```
scala> val pairs = Seq(1->"a", 2->"b", 3->"c", 4->"d")
pairs: Seq[(Int, String)] = List((1,a), (2,b), (3,c), (4,d))

scala> val d1 = (for((k, v) <- pairs) yield (k, v*2)).toMap
d1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> aa, 2 -> bb, 3 -> cc, 4 -> dd)

scala> val d2 = Map(pairs map { case(k, v) => (k*2, v) } :_*)
d2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(2 -> a, 4 -> b, 6 -> c, 8 -> d)

scala> val d3 = pairs map { case(k, v) => (k*2, v) } toMap
d3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(2 -> a, 4 -> b, 6 -> c, 8 -> d)

scala> val d4: Map[Int, String] = (for((k, v) <- pairs) yield (k, v*2))(breakOut)
d4: Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> aa, 2 -> bb, 3 -> cc, 4 -> dd)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few examples:

```
val listOfLists = Vector(Vector(1,2), Vector(3,4), Vector(5,6))

val m1 = listOfLists.map { case Seq(a,b) => (a,b) }.toMap
val m2 = listOfLists.collect { case Seq(a,b) if b>0 => (a,b) }.toMap
val m3 = (for (Seq(a,b) <- listOfLists) yield (a,b)).toMap
val m4 = (for (Seq(a,b) <- listOfLists if b>0) yield (a,b)).toMap

val m5 = Map(listOfLists.map { case Seq(a,b) => (a,b) }: _*)
val m6 = Map(listOfLists.collect { case Seq(a,b) => (a,b) }: _*)
val m7 = Map((for (Seq(a,b) <- listOfLists) yield (a,b)): _*)
val m8 = Map((for (Seq(a,b) <- listOfLists if b>0) yield (a,b)): _*)
```

You can create a `Map` using `.toMap` or `Map(xs: _*)`.  The `collect` method lets you filter as you `map`.  And a for-comprehension uses syntax most similar to your example.